# Glass Fluent Config - Could not find the configuration for type

Tags: glass-mapper

I've got a set of interfaces doing inheritance as follows (trimmed for essentials):

```
public interface IGlassBase

public interface IMetaData : IGlassBase

public interface IBaseHubPage : IMetaData

public interface IHomePage : IBaseHubPage
```

Then in the mapping classes, I have the following (again trimmed for essentials):

```
public class GlassBaseMap : SitecoreGlassMap<IGlassBase> {
  public override void Configure() {
    Map(config => ... }
  }

public class MetaDataMap : SitecoreGlassMap<IMetaData> {
  public override void Configure() {
    Map(config => { ImportMap<IGlassBase>(); }
  }

public class BaseHubPageMap : SitecoreGlassMap<IBaseHubPage> {
  public override void Configure() {
    Map(config => { ImportMap<IMetaData>(); }
  }

public class HomePageMap : SitecoreGlassMap<IHomePage> {
  public override void Configure() {
    Map(config => { ImportMap<BaseHubPageMap>(); }
  }
```

And for importing the maps in the GlassMapperScCustom file, I have this:

```
public static void AddMaps(IConfigFactory<IGlassMap> mapsConfigFactory) {
  string binPath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");

  foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(binPath, "Client*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
    try {
      Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
      Type glassmapType = typeof(IGlassMap);
      var maps = loadedAssembly.GetTypes().Where(x => glassmapType.IsAssignableFrom(x));

      if (maps != null) {
        foreach (var map in maps) {
          mapsConfigFactory.Add(() => Activator.CreateInstance(map) as IGlassMap);
        }
      }
    } catch (FileLoadException loadEx) {
    } // The Assembly has already been loaded.
    catch (BadImageFormatException imgEx) {
    } // If exception is thrown, the file is not an assembly.
  }
}
```

Everything works fine if I keep the HomePageMap out of the mix, but when I add it back in, I get this error: `Could not find the configuration for type Client.Website.Models.Configuration.BaseHubPageMap`. Is there an inheritance limit I'm hitting to prevent this from working right, or some other import or configuration process I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HomePageMap, your ImportMap call is importing the map (BaseHubPageMap) rather than the interface.

So change that map to be:

```
public class HomePageMap : SitecoreGlassMap<IHomePage> {
  public override void Configure() {
    Map(config => { ImportMap<IBaseHubPage>(); }
  }
```

Comment: Yep, I got a compilation to go after that. Thanks for the eyes, I just mixed-and-matched!

Comment: no problem!  Additional pairs of eyes are always helpful.